# How to make the parent view to handle all the OnClick events?

Tags: android, layout, onclicklistener

I have a Layout that has a button that shows another view, but only for 1 time, I mean, you click the button, it dissapear and the other view is shown, the second time you should click the parent view of that button and the other view (the one that was shown) should dissapear and the button should appear again. I am trying with `clickable:false` and `focusable:false` but it is not working. How can I achieve that?

**Relevant Code**

XML

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_tournament_header"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_card_tournament"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="15">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_friend_img_profile_pic"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"
            app:siBorderColor="@color/white"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tournament_name"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_h3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tournament_client"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_p"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_plus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_plus_tournaments"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Java

```
 btn_plus  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
        TournamentContent =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.item_tournament_content);
        TournamentHeadaer =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.item_tournament_header);

        btn_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TournamentContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn_plus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });

        TournamentHeadaer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(btn_plus.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                {
 // It's not entering here!!!
                    TournamentContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_plus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe i miss understood the problem, but i think that your problem is the logic of `if` statement :  `if(btn_plus.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)`
that should be :
`if(TournamentContent.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)` or `if(btn_plus.getVisibility()==View.GONE)`

Comment: Yeah, my miss trying to blame the tools before double check my algorithm

Answer (score 2):

```
 btn_plus  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus); 
        TournamentContent =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.item_tournament_content); 
        TournamentHeadaer =(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.item_tournament_header); 

        btn_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                TournamentContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn_plus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } 
        }); 

        TournamentHeadaer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override 
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(btn_plus.getVisibility()==View.GONE)
                { 
 // It's not entering here!!! 
                    TournamentContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_plus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } 
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your code like this:

```
btn_plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TournamentContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn_plus.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    TournamentHeadaer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(btn_plus.getVisibility()==View.INVISIBLE)
            {
                TournamentContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_plus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
```